# In IE10, is there a setting to always use Standard Document Mode?

Tags: meta-tags, internet-explorer-10, x-ua-compatible, ie-compatibility-mode, http-equiv

I created an extension for IE10 that uses X-site scripting, which does not work when Document Mode (Not the Browser Mode!) is set to below IE10.

But some of the sites that my extension runs include the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8">`, and sets the Document Mode to IE8.

I can manually change the Document Mode back to Standard using the Dev Tools, but I have to do it every time I visit the page.

Is there a setting in windows or IE10 to ignore the meta tag, and always use Standard Document Mode?